# Why does ForEach-Object behave differently when called as foreach?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, `foreach` and `%` are default aliases to `ForEach-Object`. However, it seems the command behaves differently depending upon how it is called.

Particularly, I have a hard time getting the command to work without feeding it input from the pipeline, unless I'm specifically using the `foreach` alias.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or is this by design for some reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The foreach statement and the Foreach-Object Cmdlet [NOT the same thing.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8da8249-ea91-4772-ae85-582a4b37425b/powershell-foreachobject-vs-foreach?forum=smallbusinessserver)

For one:

> In the case of the Foreach-Object, the statement body is executed as
>   soon as each object is produced. In the foreach statement, all the
>   objects are collected before the loop body begins to execute. This has
>   two implications

There are also performance and syntax differences.

```
$i = @(1..3) | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_}
```

Does work in Foreach-Object.

Comment: That line of script works for `foreach`, `ForEach-Object`, and `%`. It can even be shortened to `1..3|%{$_}`. :-)

Comment: Oh geez, don't code-golf me! @Iszi I actually work hard to write out my commands most of the time ;) I like readable code commands. But very nice.

Comment: [Why use foreach vs foreach-object?](http://bsonposh.com/archives/327) - "First it is important to understand that foreach -ne foreach-object unless used in the pipeline."

Comment: It looks like if we want to use `ForEach-Object` without piping, with syntax somewhat similar to `foreach` we can do `ForEach-Object -InputObject (1..3) {$_}` or `% -i(1..3){$_}`.

Comment: might be good to clarify in the first sentence "The foreach statement and the Foreach-Object Cmdlet are not..." - for someone who doesn't already know the answer, I think it would be helpful to further distinguish the two at first sight (?) anyone else wanna weigh in on this?

Comment: I put my suggestion in my comment: "The foreach statement and the Foreach-Object Cmdlet are not..." instead of "Foreach and Foreach-Object are not..." - just a stylistic change that I didn't see as something I should make without at least a bit of consensus

Comment: Although I don't think it changes the message, it is better English- So updated